# TFS get name of build directory inside of CodeActivity

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I am creating a TFS2013 custom activity using the CodeActivity base class.

Here is the overload I am working with...

```
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
```

With a CodeActivityContext, how does one get the build directory (where the files get dropped before being built by MSBuild)?  I need to modify a file in the build directory path prior to MSBuild taking over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass in a string to your activity

```
[RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> DirectoryToSearch { get; set; }
```

In previous versions of TFS you could just Pass in **SourcesDirectory** or **BinariesDirectory**

In 2013 the default objects for SourcesDirectory and BinariesDirectory have been withdrawn.

you can now get these from the

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables object.

[image: WellKnownEnvironmentVariables]

Comment: Today DotNetCurry just published an article on this very technique.  http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1035

Answer (score 1):

These paths are now stored in Environment variables (as of TFS 2013 I believe).

Read more about the environment variables here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh850448.aspx

The one you want is TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY

Comment: I saw those, but I wasn't clear on how to get access to those from a CodeActivity.  Can you show a quick code example please?

Comment: Just like you would in any C# code, System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY")  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx